# Remove duplicate records in a sequence

Tags: mysql

I have created one "login" table for storing users login details in it as follows (with sample data).

```
CREATE TABLE Login ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, userid int(11) DEFAULT NULL, logintime timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, status tinyint(4) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO Login (id, userid, logintime, status)
values (1,  1,  '2014-12-19 16:27:46',  -1),
       (2,  1,  '2014-12-19 16:31:18',  -1),
       (3,  1,  '2014-12-19 16:31:27',  -1),
       (4,  1,  '2014-12-19 16:31:29',  -1),
       (5,  1,  '2014-12-19 16:31:41',  1),
       (6,  2,  '2014-12-19 16:32:01',  -1),
       (7,  2,  '2014-12-19 16:32:03',  -1),
       (8,  1,  '2014-12-19 16:32:06',  -1),
       (9,  1,  '2014-12-19 16:32:37',  -1),
       (10, 2,  '2014-12-19 16:32:58',  1),
       (11, 3,  '2014-12-19 16:33:05',  1),
       (12, 4,  '2014-12-19 16:33:10',  -1),
       (13, 4,  '2014-12-19 16:33:11',  -1),
       (14, 4,  '2014-12-19 16:33:11',  -1),
       (15, 5,  '2014-12-19 16:33:16',  -1),
       (16, 3,  '2014-12-19 16:33:19',  1),
       (17, 3,  '2014-12-19 16:34:39',  1);
```

In this example field status=1 is showing successfull login and status= -1 is showing failed login.

Here I want to remove duplicate failed logins (e.g. status= -1) records except 1st record which is in sequance.
Means in my case user 1 with loginid 2,3,4 should be removed because it is come after loginid 1 in a sequance. 
then user 1 has loginid 5 with successfull login (status=1), so it should be kept, 
after that loginid 9 for user 1, should also remove because it is a duplicate record.

I want to do this for each user, and this table has at least 14 million (very huge), and I want to do It with DELETE query. Is their any query to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest that you don't approach this as a `delete`.  Instead, copy the data you want to another table, truncate the table, and re-insert it.

I would suggest using variables to get what you want.  The following identifies the records you want:

```
select l.*
from (select l.*,
             (@rn := if(@id = id and status = -1, @rn + 1,
                        if(@id := id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from login l cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @id := 0) vars
      order by id
     ) l
where seqnum = 1 or status = 1;
```

Note:  test this query to be sure it really does do what you want.

To use this:

```
create table tmp_login as
    select l.*
    from (select l.*,
                 (@rn := if(@id = id and status = -1, @rn + 1,
                            if(@id := id, 1, 1)
                           )
                 ) as rn
          from login l cross join
               (select @rn := 0, @id := 0) vars
          order by id
         ) l
    where seqnum = 1 or status = 1;

truncate table login;

insert into login(id, userid, logintime, status)
    select id, userid, logintime, status
    from tmp_login;
```

Comment: Hi @gordon-linoff, thanks for the quick reply, but it seems like some error in command.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this query, please try it (making a backup first, haha):

```
DELETE FROM Login
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT LoginDelete.id
        FROM Login LoginDelete
        LEFT JOIN Login LoginIgnore
          ON LoginIgnore.userid = LoginDelete.userid
            AND LoginIgnore.status = LoginDelete.status
            AND LoginIgnore.id < LoginDelete.id
        WHERE LoginDelete.status = -1
          AND LoginIgnore.id IS NULL
    ) as idList
)
```

What this query will do is delete every status = -1 per user, except the first logged. I used the id because it should be unique, the logintime could be repeated if failed two times in the same time.

Regards.